# Homebrew specific version of sshuttle

Tags: installation, homebrew

While I was trying to install the older version of [Sshutle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle),
I am trying to install sshuttle version 0.78.5 and using this command:

```sh
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/276d373c333dd386a9220d0f535633e15b844e17/Formula/sshuttle.rb
```

I am getting this error:

> Calling Installation of sshuttle from a GitHub commit URL is disabled!
> Use 'brew extract sshuttle' to stable tap on GitHub instead.

How do I enable the command?

Answer (score 1):

Use of `brew extract` is not trivial. I think simplest solution for you is to execute:

```
curl --silent \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/276d373c333dd386a9220d0f535633e15b844e17/Formula/sshuttle.rb \
  --output sshuttle.rb
brew install ./sshuttle.rb
```